# X Android SDK file not found : C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\aapt

Tags: android, flutter

I just tried intalling flutter and since I already had android studio and the android sdk installed I just followed the installation of flutter. Here is my problem: When I run

flutter doctor
It tells me

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.208], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\aapt.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Answer (score 1):

The error says `X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\aapt.`.
But it can't find an android SDK in this path, because this is a path for `aapt`.

It also has something else wrong with it, notice two forward slashes after Users:`C:\Users\\AppData`, this is also causing a problem.

Use this command to point it in the correct place, assuming your android SDK is there:

`flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\`

Then run flutter doctor, and update what happens.